# Meaning of Ephesians 3:3b

Tags: ephesians

[Ephesians 3:3b "as I have already written briefly."](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Ephesians%203%3A3&version=NIV)

Does Paul mean earlier in that very letter (seems unlikely he would feel the need to say that) or is it a previous letter to the Ephesians that we do not have, or something else?

Answer (score 1):

Ellicott notes this about Eph 3:3 -

> **As I wrote afore in few words**.—The reference is to the brief notice in Ephesians 1:10-14, and to the further explanation in
> Ephesians 2:11-22. Hence, in English, the idea would be more clearly
> expressed by “I have written above.” St. Paul refers them back to
> these passages as embodying his “understanding,” or conception, of the
> mystery thus revealed especially to him. The reference is one of those
> parenthetical remarks, which, to those remembering how St. Paul’s
> Epistles were dictated, almost irresistibly suggest insertion on the
> reading over of the Epistle.

Specifically, Paul is referring to the subject raised in the first part of the verse, namely:

> How that **by revelation he made known unto me the mystery**; (as I wrote
> afore in few words)

Thus, Paul refers back to his earlier explanation.  Note the comments of the Cambridge commentary which are similar:

> **as I wrote afore** The reference is to previous passages in this Epistle; Ephesians 1:9, &c., Ephesians 2:11, &c. English idiom would
> say, as I have written afore.